# Using Jquery to change div

Tags: jquery, html

UPDATE: So I put all the divs under one table data cell. Now I get the functionality that I want when changing the selection option, but it shows **all** the divs when the page loads up. I just want it to show my pre-selection under `{html_options name="program" options=$programs selected=$sanction->Program}`

The $sanction->Program piece brings in a string of what program is to be preselected. It selects the actual option on the option set initially, but the value is not corresponding. It just shows **every** div.

PREVIOUS:
I am trying to hide my divs in jquery while showing one div. When I select my one option from six..the div shows up, but you can clearly tell while going through the selections that they are on top of each other. I just want to hide the other divs when I make my one selection and just show that one div. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code

//JQUERY

```
        $("select[name=program]").change(function () {
            $("td#levelCheck div").hide();
            $("td#levelCheck div#" + $(this).val()).show();
        });
```

//HTML

```
    <table class="form" style="margin-top: 20px;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Sanction Name</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="name" size="40" maxlength="100" value="{$sanction->Name}" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th style="vertical-align: top;">Select discipline type</th>
                    <td>{html_options name="program" options=$programs selected=$sanction->Program}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="trCheck">
                    <th></th>
                    <td id="levelCheck">
                        <div id="Rhythmic" style="width: 452px;">
                            {foreach from=$acroLevels item=level}
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="{$level->Code}" value="{$level->Description}" /> {$level->Description}
                                </label>
                            {/foreach}
                        </div>
                        <div id="Acro" style="width: 452px;">
                            {foreach from=$acroLevels item=level}
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="{$level->Code}" value="{$level->Description}" /> {$level->Description}
                                </label>
                            {/foreach}
                        </div>
                        <div id="Men" style="width: 452px;">
                            {foreach from=$mensLevels item=level}
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="{$level->Code}" value="{$level->Description}" /> {$level->Description}
                                </label>
                            {/foreach}
                        </div>
                        <div id="TT" style="width: 452px;">
                            {foreach from=$ttLevels item=level}
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="{$level->Code}" value="{$level->Description}" /> {$level->Description}
                                </label>
                            {/foreach}
                        </div>
                        <div id="Women" style="width: 452px;">
                            {foreach from=$womensLevels item=level}
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="{$level->Code}" value="{$level->Description}" /> {$level->Description}
                                </label>
                            {/foreach}
                        </div>
                        <div id="Group" style="display: none;">
                   </td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: In what way can you clearly tell that they're on top of one another? What does the user experience or see that you do not want them to? Without a working example, it "looks" OK on first inspection.

Comment: If you are using an id in your selector, you don't need to specify any other information. It should be unique in the document already. `$('#' + $(this).val())`

Comment: The dropdown selector comes pre-populated with a value from my controller which shows the div associated with the option. The problem is I want all the other divs not to show while one selection is highlighted. Basically there is a lot of space being taken up from the selections. I only want a limited amount of space for just one div.

Comment: I'm not trying to display the other divs. I just want one div to display at a time. Not all of them on the page. I want one div to replaced by the other, only taking up space for one div. Hopefully this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple TDs with same ID

```
<td id="levelCheck">
```

In this case the jQuery would apply selectors using #levelCheck to only the first matched element not all as you would expect. You should change it to use a class instead

```
<td class="levelCheck">
```

and then use

```
$("td.levelCheck div")
```

Answer (score 0):

Throw that ugly table away. Just put all div's plain after each other and set display to none.
The one you want to show, you set display to block, all others to none.
That's all.